# Is there any mistake in this sentence below? Should 'it' be deleted in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I saw the sentence like this
[image]

What memories do you think it will happen today?

I think 'it' is an unnecessary word for this sentence.

What is the meaning of the sentence above?

And is there any grammatical error in the sentence above?

sorry, I have no more context in the sentence. That is the campaign title.

Comment: That "it" is incorrect, yes. I think they meant to ask, "What memories do you think will be made today?" (Which sounds a bit clumsy to me, but better than the original because I don't think"happen" is the right word when talking about memories.)

Comment: typical of English translation errors in non native English speaking regions

Comment: Thank you for your help~thank you so much